# Matlab: == in parameters to function: sum(var==0)

Tags: matlab

A piece of partial code I'm working on for an assignment has the following:

```
turn=10-sum(state==0);
```

I can't figure out what's going on here for the life of me.

Comment: `state==0` checks whether each element of `state` is 0. `state==0` is a vector, the same size as `state`, with a 1 where the corresponding element of `state` is 0, and 0 where the corresponding element of `state` is not exactly 0. Does that help?

Comment: Also, note that if `state` is an array, `sum` will give a the sum _along the first non-singleton dimension_ of the array. For example, if `state=[5 0 0; 4 3 0]`, then `sum(state==0)` will give the row vector `[0 1 2]`´

Comment: Also also note that if you're lazy, you can just say `sum(~state)` to the same effect. But that's admittedly less transparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`state==0` compares every element of `state` for equality with `0` and creates a new matrix of the same dimensions as `state`. This new matrix will contain a `1` when `state` is equal (`==`) to `0` and a `0` when `state` does not equal (`~=`) `0`.

For example

```
>> state = [1 0 2; 4 6 0];
>> state==0
ans =

     0     1     0
     0     0     1
```

here we can clearly see that the only non-zero elements of `state==0` are those in `state` which equal `0`.

[`sum`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) will then sum all the elements of `state==0` along the first dimension that does not equal `1`. For a vector example, which I presume is what you are dealing with, `sum()` will in this problem count the number of elements in `state` that are equal to `0`.

```
>> state = [1 0 4 0 3 2 5 0];
>> sum(state==0)
ans =

     3
```

Putting this all together

```
>> state = [1 0 4 0 3 2 5 0];
>> turn=10-sum(state==0)

turn =

     7
```